# Internet Explorer 8 Messing Up My Bulletgraphs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, excanvas

I've created HTML and JavaScript files to display bulletgraphs, using the 'canvas' HTML5 tag. I've tried it in Chrome and it works nicely and changes width along with the size of the browser. I have to have this working in IE8, too, so I've used Excanvas, which is working in all except one way: when I resize the browser I get remnants of the valueIndicator. This only happens on IE8.

I've tried looking round for information on redrawing the canvas but I don't think this is the issue. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong, please?

***EDIT***
I'm keeping the complete code at the bottom, however, following advice I've cut my code down somewhat.

In IE8 it looks like this:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6985149/MessedUp.bmp]

In Chrome it looks like this:

[image]

When I refresh the IE8 page it looks OK again.

Cut-down Bulletgraph.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bulletgraph</title>
        <!--[if IE]><script src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="graph1"></canvas>
        <script src="Scripts.js"></script>
        <script>
            drawGraphs();
            window.onresize=function() { drawGraphs() };

            function drawGraphs() {
                drawBulletGraph(getScreenWidth(),300,1000,350,"graph1");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Complete code:**

Cut-down Scripts.js:

```
function drawBulletGraph (cwidth, left, right, loValue, id) {
    var canvas=document.getElementById(id);
    var cheight=30;

    var multiplier=cwidth/(right-left);
    canvas.width=cwidth;
    canvas.height=cheight;

    var valueIndicator=canvas.getContext("2d");
    valueIndicator.lineWidth="1";
    valueIndicator.moveTo((loValue-left)*multiplier,0);
    valueIndicator.lineTo((loValue-left)*multiplier,cheight);
    valueIndicator.fill();
    valueIndicator.stroke();
}

function getScreenWidth () {
    return (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)/7;
}
```

Bulletgraph.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bulletgraph</title>
        <!--[if IE]><script src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="graph1"></canvas><br>
        <canvas id="graph2"></canvas>
        <script src="Scripts.js"></script>
        <script>
            drawGraphs();
            window.onresize=function() { drawGraphs() };

            function drawGraphs() {
                drawBulletGraph(bgWidth(getScreenWidth()),300,400,450,600,700,1000,800,350,850,"graph1");
                drawBulletGraph(bgWidth(getScreenWidth()),250,450,500,650,700,1200,600,350,850,"graph2");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Scripts.js:

```
function drawBulletGraph (cwidth, left, loRed, loAmber, hiAmber, hiRed, right, value, loValue, hiValue, id) {
    var canvas=document.getElementById(id);
    var cheight=16;
    var colour="#008000";
    if (value <= loRed || value >= hiRed)
        {
            colour="#FF0000";
        }
    else if (value <= loAmber || value >= hiAmber)
        {
            colour="#FFA500";
        }
    var multiplier=cwidth/(right-left);
    canvas.width=cwidth;
    canvas.height=cheight;
    var red=canvas.getContext("2d");
    red.fillStyle="#F4C3C6";
    red.fillRect(0,0,cwidth,cheight);
    var amber=canvas.getContext("2d");
    amber.fillStyle="#F4F6C6";
    amber.fillRect((loRed-left)*multiplier,0,(hiRed-loRed)*multiplier,cheight);
    var green=canvas.getContext("2d");
    green.fillStyle="#CCE5CC";
    green.fillRect((loAmber-left)*multiplier,0,(hiAmber-loAmber)*multiplier,cheight);
    var valueIndicator=canvas.getContext("2d");
    valueIndicator.fillStyle=colour;
    valueIndicator.strokeStyle=colour;
    valueIndicator.lineWidth="2";
    valueIndicator.moveTo((loValue-left)*multiplier,0);
    valueIndicator.lineTo((loValue-left)*multiplier,cheight);
    valueIndicator.moveTo((loValue-left)*multiplier,cheight/2);
    valueIndicator.lineTo((hiValue-left)*multiplier,cheight/2);
    valueIndicator.moveTo((hiValue-left)*multiplier,0);
    valueIndicator.lineTo((hiValue-left)*multiplier,cheight);
    valueIndicator.moveTo(((value-left)*multiplier)-(cheight/2),cheight/2);
    valueIndicator.stroke();
    valueIndicator.lineWidth="1";
    valueIndicator.lineTo((value-left)*multiplier,cheight);
    valueIndicator.lineTo(((value-left)*multiplier)+(cheight/2),cheight/2);
    valueIndicator.lineTo((value-left)*multiplier,0);
    valueIndicator.lineTo(((value-left)*multiplier)-(cheight/2),cheight/2);
    valueIndicator.fill();
    valueIndicator.stroke();
}

function getScreenWidth () {
    return window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}

function bgWidth (screenWidth) {
    var graphWidth=screenWidth/7;
    if (graphWidth<70) {graphWidth=70;}
    if (graphWidth>260) {graphWidth=260;}
    return graphWidth;
}
```

Comment: You should *throttle resize* since it gets fired multiple times.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the issue? Have you at least narrowed down the problem to a specific element or block of code? If it's a rendering issue, can you provide screenshots of the problem and how you expect it to appear?

Comment: Hi, thanks to you both for your responses. @epascarello - How would I do that, please? I've had a look around and can't figure it out.

Comment: @Tragedian - I can't upload images, unfortunately, because my reputation is too low.
As for what I've tried, I have removed the rectangles (named red, amber, green) and the problem persists, so the problem is with the valueIndicator drawing, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you reduce the example code to the minimum required to produce the problem? Narrowing down the problem will make it much more likely to be answered. You should be able to upload the images to any online storage (SkyDrive for example) and embed them in the message question. If you can't embed them, then add them as links and somebody with enough reputation will do so. This information is essential to be sure your problem has been reproduced.

Comment: @Tragedian - Thanks for the advice. I've editted my question and I hope it's more answerable now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get a solution. It feels like a bit of a hack but it does the trick. Basically it involves drawing a white line round the canvas and filling it each time it's drawn again. The following code goes between the `var valueIndicator=canvas.getContext("2d");` and the `valueIndicator.lineWidth="1";` lines:

```
valueIndicator.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
valueIndicator.strokeStyle="#FFFFFF";
valueIndicator.moveTo(0,0);
valueIndicator.beginPath();
valueIndicator.lineTo(0,cheight);
valueIndicator.lineTo(cwidth,cheight);
valueIndicator.lineTo(cwidth,0);
valueIndicator.closePath();
valueIndicator.fill();
valueIndicator.stroke();
valueIndicator.strokeStyle="#000000";
```

I've tried it in the full code and it works. If anyone has a more elegant solution, and I'm sure there must be many, I would still love to see them.